# Which anchors to use for a wall in a basement

Tags: concrete, walls, basement

I need to extend one of the walls by approx 30 inches.

I will be using pressure treaded 2x4 in bottom of the wall and wall will be about 83 inches high.

Which anchors should I use to secure the wall to the concrete floor? How long they should be?

Will Tapcon 1/4 x 3” work for this project?

How many anchors will I need? I was planning to use three: both ends and somewhere in the middle.

Thanks.

Comment: A liberal bead of construction adhesive is all it would take.

Comment: @isherwood I couldn’t didn’t the answer of length of the screws/nails to use. I read many and answers answering this question.

Comment: Length isn't critical as you aren't dealing with pullout forces. 3" are plenty. If they make a 2-1/2" I'd probably buy that. A couple galvanized 16d or 20d nails driven together into a 3/16" hole also works well.

Comment: @isherwood thanks. Please add it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Answers cannot be provided for questions closed as duplicates. I realize that the answers on other questions don't address your specific questions, but the general knowledge they provide lead to the answer. It's just not that critical.